# Rewriting this exponential in terms of n

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm having trouble rewriting this in terms of n. I'm trying to compare this with other asymptotic functions.

$$16^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$$

I have these other ones which I have already ordered: $\log_2 n, (\log_2 \log_2 n)^2, (\log_2 n)^2, \sqrt{n},$ and $2^{\log_3 n}$

I know that for something like $2^{\log_3 n}$, you can rewrite it as $n^{\log_3 2}$

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Isn't it already in terms of $n$?

Comment: @MPW he likely wants $n$ as the base of the expression

Comment: Yeah, sorry if that wasn't clear. I wanted n as the base of the expression so I could compare it with the other ones and place it in order

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to have something involving $n^{\textrm{something without }n}$ ?

Comment: Yeah exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we obtain
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
16^{\sqrt{\log_2(n)}}
&=& n^{\log_{n}(16) \sqrt{\log_2(n)}} \tag{$\small a = b^{\log_b(a)}$} \\
&=& n^{\sqrt{\log_2(n) \cdot \log_{n}(16) \cdot \log_{n}(16)}} \tag{$\small a = \sqrt{a \cdot a}$} \\
&=& n^{\sqrt{\log_2(16) \cdot \log_{n}(16)}} \tag{$\small \log_a(b) = \log_a(c) \cdot \log_c(b)$} \\
&=& n^{\sqrt{4 \cdot \log_{n}(16)}} \\
&=& n^{\sqrt{\log_{n}(65536)}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
However, you cannot get rid of the $n$ in the exponent, because of the root.